# spring-Security page redirect Issue

Tags: spring, session, spring-mvc, spring-security

1. First of all am new to spring security.
   my Question is when I authenticate a user from form and redirect to a url of controller handler method and  get a view.Then after user click a link,Then how to authenticate that url and other particular user.
2. This thing I did in Session validation in every jsp normal java with out spring security.
3. How to achieve this in spring security.

Comment: Your first point is not clear. Can you elaborate your issue clearly..

Comment: once a user authenticate and get a view.then he will click for another resource like(accounts detail or edit his credential).on this how to authenticate that user in spring security.